# ZigBee sleep problem

Tags: zigbee, mesh-networks

I recently built a XBee network (using Firmware version 9000 of Digimesh 2.4 TH function set of XB24c family). Currently I use the DTR pin to put XBee to sleep, and this configuration works perfectly. But I read that this is not a good solution as the mesh must be made again when a node leaves or joins network.

DigiMesh 2.4 allows an Sleep mode with SM=7 or SM=8 where they sleep synchronously. When updating the firmware with XCTU, it does not show SM 7 and 8 options.

Is there any other thing I should set, or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you built a Zigbee network using Digimesh protocol. The thing is that this is an impossibility: Zigbee and Digimesh are competing solutions for mesh network, not something you use together.

See this link: [Digimesh manufacturer explains the difference between Zigbee and Digimesh](https://www.digi.com/blog/networking/what-are-the-differences-between-digimesh-and-zigbee-mesh/)

Digimesh uses Sleep Modes 7 and 8 whereas Zigbee uses 4 and 5. Have you accidentally changed to use Zigbee instead of Digimesh? That would be the reason why you don't see SM 7 and 8 anymore.

**Edit:**

Looking docs of XB24c they have now also adopted SM numbers 4 and 5.

Look:
 https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90001506.pdf

Comment: No, it use DigiMesh protocol, not ZigBee Mesh. To be precise network uses `Firmware version 9000` of `Digimesh 2.4 TH function set` of `XB24c family`.

Comment: Hmm, looking docs of XB24c they have now also adopted SM numbers 4 and 5. Look: https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90001506.pdf

Comment: SM number 4 and 5 are different for XB24c and XB24 family (which i didn't knew). Thanks for pointing that out.